# How to open attachment in Android app without using WebViewActivtiy

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, attachment, qlpreviewcontroller

My app get a url string from an api call. I show an icon on my UI and when user clicks on it I want to open the pdf so users can preview it and read it. If they want to download or share the attachment I want to support this functionality swell. However I could not find the best way to do this. Can you please help me?

P.S: we can do this in iOS using QLPreviewController, but not sure what the equivalent for it in android is.

Comment: An `url string` becomes a `the pdf` and then `the attachment`. Any more transformations?

Comment: yes I get the url. url can be of any type image or pdf. I need to view preview it in my app. No more transformations.